# ionic 2 Not able to download ios build from ionic.io

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I run below command

1 **ionic package build ios --profile appname**

2 **ionic package info build_id(12)**

```
Caught exception:
     SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
        at Object.parse (native)
        at Request._callback (C:\Users\CakeDev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\package.js:117:27)
        at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\CakeDev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\request\request.js:373:22)
        at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
        at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CakeDev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\request\request.js:1318:14)
        at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
        at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CakeDev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\request\request.js:1266:12)

        at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
```